# Cannot connect to PostgreSQL replica

Tags: postgresql, replication

I can't to connect to PostgreSQL replica.
When I try to connect to PostgreSQL replica it shows error message:

**psql: error: FATAL:  canceling statement due to conflict with recovery
DETAIL:  User query might have needed to see row versions that must be removed**

This message appears when connect local and over the network.

Log entry:

```
2022-06-14 17:04:32 [4158196]: [1-1] db=[unknown],user=[unknown],app=[unknown],client=[local],LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2022-06-14 17:04:32 [4158196]: [2-1] db=postgres,user=postgres,app=[unknown],client=[local],LOG:  connection authorized: user=postgres database=postgres application_name=psql
2022-06-14 17:04:32 [4158196]: [3-1] db=postgres,user=postgres,app=[unknown],client=[local],FATAL:  canceling statement due to conflict with recovery
2022-06-14 17:04:32 [4158196]: [4-1] db=postgres,user=postgres,app=[unknown],client=[local],DETAIL:  User query might have needed to see row versions that must be removed.
```

So I get the connection but it immediately terminate.**The replica hasn't user connections, only system processes, so no query are made on it.**

**Note:**
I get this error when try to connect to the replica, and don't execute any query.

Replica has next settings:

show hot_standby=on

max_standby_archive_delay=30s

max_standby_streaming_delay=30s

wal_receiver_status_interval=10s

hot_standby_feedback=on

wal_receiver_timeout=1min

wal_retrieve_retry_interval=3s

Version:
PostgreSQL 13.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5), 64-bit

What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: If the replica hasn't user connections, then what is it that receives the error?

Comment: This error I get when try to connect to replica with psql.

Comment: It is weird that you would get this error from a connection which hasn't run any statements, but the answer listed in the close reason should still apply.  Also, 13.2 is pretty old, you should upgrade to 13.7.  Is this 100% reproducible, or does it only occur sometimes?

Comment: It happens sometimes. I suppose, that the reason is the increased load on the master DB.